# Por que a função ZipFile não está funcionando?

Tags: c#

Achei uma função no [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh485707(v=vs.110).aspx) que eu estou precisando usar para um programa que estou fazendo.
O meu problema, é que quando tento utiliza-la ela aparece como se não existisse no C#[,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdhoVJLIWv8) lembrando que já adicionei o `using System.IO;` ao topo do meu programa. É preciso fazer alguma referência para usa-lo?

```
static void backup(string path)
{
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path);
}
```

Erro:

> Erro   CS0103  O nome "ZipFile" não existe no contexto atual

Comment: Precisamos saber oque acontece, como está o código.

Comment: @bigown Como não está clara o suficiente se o Tiago conseguiu me responder com precisão?

Comment: Porque ele deu um bom chute. A resposta dele provavelmente está correta. Mas na pergunta não há informação que indique bem o que estava acontecendo. Se vier outra pessoa aqui não será ajudado porque não se sabe bem qual é o problema.

Comment: @bigown Pronto, adicionei mais informações, pode tirar a marcação agora?

Comment: Sim, agora tá ok, se todos fizessem assim, seria fácil, não? Me ajudou bastante no meu próximo post no meta :)

Comment: Não vou entrar em discussão, mas a resposta certa é apenas a do @bigown, caso não foi ele que deu a resposta é chute ou está errada. Ou se a pergunta não está no nível dele é de baixa qualidade e é fechada. Infelizmente nós meros mortais não podemos fazer nada contra isso.

Comment: @TiagoS eu falei o oposto do que você está afirmando. Eu dei mais de 1000 respostas de C# e .NET. Alguma resposta minha é boa? Ou eu errei em (quase) todas? Deixar de votar nas respostas dos outros é dizer com clareza que só as próprias respostas são boas.

Comment: @TiagoS É uma questão de utilidade deste post. O site não tá aqui pra prestar suporte pra ninguém. Ele serve pra ajudar em problemas específicos, mas espera que isso seja útil para outras pessoas também... A pergunta na forma original não estava clara e sua resposta (apesar de certa) foi um chute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar a referência `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` no seu projeto

Fonte: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx)